# Place components at arbitrary (x,y) coordinates

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jbutton

I want to place some buttons in a `JPanel` at random positions (x,y), and these layout classes are annoying.

Is this even possible in Swing?

Comment: It's better to learn about different [Layout Managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html).

Comment: No, you definitely _do not want_ to do any swing layout manually. And no, there's nothing annoying about layoutManagers - except you think learning is annoying in itself ;-)

Comment: why is everybody second-guessing the op? maybe he just needs complete control over the buttons positions (like for example in some kind of game where they move around and the user has to hit them).

Comment: @fortran *"complete control over the buttons"*  If you have the logic needed to maintain that 'control' in a logical sense - put it in a custom layout manager.

Comment: @AndrewThompson why? If I just want to shake them randomly (for example), what is the advantage of putting it in a custom layout manager?

Comment: Post an actual (working*) example on a separate question & I might be willing to discuss it further.  * And by 'working' I mean works for a variety of components & PLAFs in a resizable GUI.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can set the coordinates if you use a null layout:

```
panel.setLayout(null);
Button b = new Button(....);
panel.add(b);
b.setSize(width, height);
b.setLocation(x,y);
```

But it is strongly recommended to use layouts. Layout classes are not "annoying", they are your friend if you understand them properly.

I propose reading a [tutorial about GridBagLayout](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-JFC/GridBagLayoutwithconstraints.htm), it is easy to understand (kinda html tables) and very powerful.

Comment: +1 for recommending LayoutManagers, -0.5 for doing manual layout incompletely (hach, nicely prooving the usefulness of managers ... :-)

Answer (score 5):

use `null` as "Layout Manager":

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/none.html

Comment: that is what I wrote before editing, but then I realised that someone might try to look for a class called like that ^_^

Comment: @kleopatra what kind of problem do you have?

Comment: no problem at all, it's simple wrong to propagate usage of null layout :-)

Comment: See [setLayout(null) is never necessary. Ever!](https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=1351374) for more discussion on the matter.

Comment: @AndrewThompson creating a custom LayoutManager that does the same as the null layout when you really need to place components "manually" seems too add unnecessary layers and complexity

Comment: Try it (and make it work for `null` layout across the range of circumstances outlined in the linked thread) to find out different.